# Normality of a subgroup and homomorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let H be a subgroup of G. Our textbook says "We define the canonical map, $\pi : G \rightarrow G/H$, by $\pi(x)=xH$ for $x \in G$."

But there is another theorem in the textbook that says that H is normal in G if an only if $f: G \rightarrow G/H$ is a homomorphism. I think this is a bit confusing, because isn't 
$\pi : G \rightarrow G/H$ also a homomorphism? For example, if a and b are elements of H...

$\pi(a)\pi(b) = aHbH$ and $\pi(ab)=abH$ But isn't aHbH equal to abH? So isn't $\pi$ automatically a homomorphism?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That thing you say your book says is very weird. What book is that and where's the quote from in it, please?

Comment: @DonAntonio Which part do you want me to quote? (the part where it says that f is a homomorphism if and only if H is normal?)

Comment: Yes, @Artus. Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio Let H be a subgroup of G. Then H is normal in G if and only if
there is a group structure on the set G/H of left cosets of H with the property that the
canonical map π : G → G/H is a homomorphism.
If H is normal in G, then the group structure on G/H which makes π a homomorphism is
unique: we must have gH · gH = ggH for all g, g ∈ G. Moreover, the kernel of
π : G → G/H is H. Thus, a subgroup of G is normal if and only if it is the kernel of a
homomorphism out of G.

Comment: I see, @Artus: thanks. I though found this "weird" since the usual structure given on the set of left(right) cosets $\,G/H\,$ gives a group iff $\,H\triangleleft G\,$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio This is the textbook if you want to see it http://www.albany.edu/~mark/algebra.pdf Definition 3.2.6 defines what G/H is and requires H only to be a subgroup (p.53)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Artus. Very interesting way to treat these things, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then the map $\pi:x\longmapsto xH$ is well-defined, surjective, and sends $1$ to $H$.

If $H$ is normal (ie $xH=Hx$ for all $x\in G$), we have
$$
\pi(xy)=xyH=xHy=xHHy=xHyH=\pi(x)\pi(y).
$$
This shows simultaneously that $G/H$ is a group and that $\pi$ is a surjective group homomorphism.

Conversely, if $\pi$ is multiplicative (ie $\pi(xy)=\pi(x)\pi(y)$ for all $x,y\in G$), we have
$$
H=xx^{-1}H=xHx^{-1}H\quad\Rightarrow\quad xHx^{-1}=HH^{-1}=H.
$$
So $H$ is normal.

Answer (score 1):

No. You should remember what *sort* of object $G/H$ is. If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $G/H$ is just a set, or actually a set together with a left action from $G$ (given by $g' \cdot gH := g'gH$). In this setting, $G \to G/H, g \mapsto gH$ is a homomorphism of left $G$-sets.

Now, $G/H$ is a group in such a way that $G \to G/H$ is a homomorphism of groups if and only if $H$ is a normal subgroup if and only if $Hg=gH$ for all $g \in G$ if and only if $aHbH = abH$ for all $a,b \in G$.